# Duda sobre excepciones en python

Tags: python, bucles, excepciones

Hola a toda la comunidad

Soy nuevo en esto de usar Python y tengo una duda. Estoy realizando un trabajo con una base de datos donde tengo una columna con texto string y quiero sacar la información "por partes" ya que en la columna se encuentran pasos que deben de realizar los ciudadanos para realizar un trámite. Por ejemplo, este es un  registro que se encuentra en la base

> l. Es optativo para las IMF u Organizaciones realizar el trámite de
> manera presencial en la Ventanilla Única del PR,ONAFIM para realizar
> el trámite, de lunes a viernes en un horario de g:oo a 18:00 horas. 2.
> Debe acudir el Representate Legal de la IMF u Organización ,·

Debo separar en una columna distinta la información del punto uno y en otra la información del punto 2.

Para esto creí conveniente realizar un bucle para que me arrojara la posición de los números (1. y 2.), y a partir de ahí extraer la información de la cadena.

Asimismo tuve que agregar un `except`, ya que no todos los registros cuentan con numeración y si intento sacar la posición me arroja un `ValueError`.

Por lo tanto, mi código queda de la siguiente manera, donde

- separado: Es el nombre del dataframe
- separado['Nuevo1']: Es el lugar donde se encuentra la cadena de texto de donde quiero extraer la información. Debo de indicar que esta cadena la pasé a una lista a través de un .str.split()
- separado['Index_2']: Es el nombre de la columna nueva donde se va a guardar la posición del número a buscar, que en esta función es el '2.'

*Código*

```
for i in separado.index:
    try:
        if separado['Nuevo1'].str.index('2.') > 0:
            separado[i,'Index_2']= separado.str.index[i,'Nuevo1']    
    except ValueError:
            separado['Index_2'] = 0
```

Al generar el código y exportar la base a Excel, en toda la columna nueva `separado['Index_2']` me arroja valores de cero, por lo que no entiendo qué puede estar mal en mi código

Espero me puedan apoyar con la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que

```
separado['Index_2'] = 0
```

asigna cero a la columna completa.

Si quieres asignar sólo una celda, tienes que usar

```
separado.at[i, 'Index_2'] = 0
```

Comment: Ok amigo, ya lo realicé pero en la columna me sigue apareciendo todo cero y no el número de posición en la que se encuentra el número '2.'